# Gluing locally defined continous functions over complex domain

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, complex-analysis

Suppose $n, l, m \in \mathbb N$ and $n \ge l > m$. Let $T: \mathbb C \to \mathcal M(n \times l; \mathbb C)$ be continuous and $T(\lambda)$ has constant rank $m$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. Suppose for every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, there is an open neighborhood $U(\lambda)$ of $\lambda$ and a locally defined continuous function $h_{\lambda}: U(\lambda) \to \mathcal M(n \times m; \mathbb C)$ where the image $h_{\lambda}(\beta)$ is a basis for $T(\beta)$ for every point $\beta \in U(\lambda)$. Could we construct a globally continuous function $\phi: \mathbb C \to \mathcal M(n \times m; \mathbb C)$ by gluing together these locally defined $h_{\lambda}$'s, such that
 the image $\phi(x)$, of every point $x \in \mathbb C$, is a basis for $T(x)$?

What I have in mind: Suppose we have two continuous families of $g_1: \mathbb C \supseteq U_1 \to \mathcal M(n \times m; \mathbb C)$ and $g_2 : \mathbb C \supseteq U_2 \to \mathcal M(n \times m; \mathbb C)$ where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two open disks in $\mathbb C$ with $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$. Then $(g_1^1(x), \dots, g_1^m(x))$ is a basis for $T(x)$ for all $x \in U_1$ and $(g_2^1(y), \dots, g_2^m(y))$ is a basis for $T(y)$ for all $y \in U_2$ where $g_i^j: x \mapsto \mathbf c_j( g_i(x))$ where $\mathbf c_j(\cdot)$ denotes the operation of taking the $j^{th}$ column of a matrix.  Now for every $y \in U_2 \cap U_1$, ${g}_1 (y) = g_2(y) S(y)$ for some $S(y) \in GL_m(\mathbb C)$. It follows $S(y) = (g_2^T(y) g_2(y))^{-1} g_2^T(y) g_1(y)$. By Cramer's rule, $S(y)$ is continuous with respect to $y$. That is we have a well defined continuous function on $U_1 \cap U_2$, $S \colon U_1 \cap U_2 \to GL_m(\mathbb C)$. Since $U_1 \cap U_2$ is simply connected, there is a continuous retract $r :\mathbb C \to U_1 \cap U_2$. It follows $S \circ r : \mathbb C \to GL_m(\mathbb C)$ is well defined and continuous with $S \circ r|_{U_1 \cap U_2} = S$. So we can define $g$ by
  \begin{align*}
    g(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      g_1(x), & \text{ if } x \in U_1 \setminus U_2 \\
      g_2(x)(S\circ r)(x) , & \text{ if } x \in U_2.
    \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
  This function is clearly continuous by construction and satisfies the prescribed condition.

I am not sure whether above argument is completely correct. Even if it was correct, my problem to proceed is: after we glue some collection of maps, the domain $U$ would become not so "regular". I am not sure the intersection of $U$ and an open disk would still be simple connected.

---

This question has been asked for sometime without answer and I changed the setup a little bit, so it is a little inconsistent with the comments below.

---

Comment: Um, do you want $\phi$ to somehow be related to the $h_\lambda$?  Also, do you mean for your functions to take values in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: Yes, it should be $\mathbb C^{n^2}$. What I have in mind is some constructive method if any such that: for any curve passing through a fixed point $x_0 \in \mathbb C$, I can have some $\phi$ such that $\phi$ agrees with $h_{x_0}$ locally, similar to real case.

Comment: why don't you just choose an element $A \in GL_n(\Bbb C)$ and pick the constant map $\phi(z) = A$ for every $z \in \Bbb C$ ?

Comment: @mercio: Indeed, in my situation, the columns of the images are coming from a specified set also linear transformation are allowed. Is it possible to paste together these maps similar to the real case?

Comment: I'd expect the answer to this to be related to something like $H^1(\mathbb{C}, GL_m(\mathbb{C}))$.